# Large gap after newpage or breakpage

Tags: page-breaking

Why there is a large gap when I use \newpage or \pagebreak?[image]

Comment: Without information about what is on this page and the one after we cannot help. My guess you have something on the next page that was moved there. For example a [H] float or a large align

Comment: Probably you have the default `\flushbottom` directive enabled. See what happens if you add `\raggedbottom` to your preamble.

Comment: No sir. I have just acknowledgement after/ I will send it later

Comment: Sorry \raggedbottom where should I put? I did not get it

Comment: `\raggedbottom` in the preamble normally, but normally twoside and book settings use flush bottom so the bottom line of each page is at the same place. So if you force a page to have  short content tex has to stretch the space. Just as in line breaking if you force a line with `\linebreak`  then the inter-word spacing is stretched to justify the text.

Comment: Oh great Thank you all